# AngularJS - bootstrap - bootstrapDualListbox - on select values on left side all are selecting/moving to right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrapDualListbox`

`JS`

```
      $('select[name="duallistbox_demo1[]"]').bootstrapDualListbox({
        moveOnSelect: false
      });
```

`HTML`

`<select multiple="multiple" size="10" name="duallistbox_demo1[]" ng-model="selectedStaff"><option ng-repeat="staff in staffs" value="{{staff.userId}}">{{staff.firstName}} {{staff.lastName}}</option>
  </select>`

If I use options as different values(not from ngRepeat) swapping is fine. If I use from ng-repeat, on selection all values are swapping rather selected. How I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please check using ng-options with select instead of options with ng-repeat.

```
<select multiple="multiple" size="10" ng-options="staff as staff.firstName for staff in staffs track by staff.userId" name="duallistbox_demo1[]" ng-model="selectedStaff">
```